# How to preview an image with TFileOpenDialog

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

Does anyone know how to display an image in the TFileOpenDialog preview?

I am using ImageEn to display image information and to add additional file type support to the dialog.  For example... I can load image information about jp2, j2k and other files types not supported, but how to load an unsupported image type for preview using ImageEn.

I am displaying image information in the dialog that works nicely, but I can not find any information about how to load an unsupported image into the PreviewHandler anywhere.  I can use ImageEnIO to get the file information as well as a bitmap of the image.

[image: TFileOpenDialog]

Does TFileOpenDialog use a preview handler to display the image or is some other way needed?

I am sorry I do not have code to show for displaying the image, but I do not know how to implement it.

Rodrigo commented on Hosting Preview Handlers in Delphi VCL Applications. that the windows explorer does not use a preview handler to preview the images... so I assume the TFileOpenDialog uses the same API as Windows Explorer, but I am not even sure of this. http://theroadtodelphi.wordpress.com/2013/05/24/hosting-preview-handlers-in-delphi-vcl-applications/

If this question is too broad to be accepted here I will delete the question.

Comment: would OpenPictureDialog be an option?

Comment: No... I know how to do that.  Need to do it with TFileOpenDialog.

Comment: @RRUZ, Remy Lebeau has posted Use IShellItemImageFactory instead, as it delegates to  IThumbnailProvider internally (and to IExractImage and IExtractIcon when  IThumbnailProvider is not available). http://embarcadero.newsgroups.archived.at/public.delphi.nativeapi/201007/1007283828.html
Is it better to use IShellItemImageFactory?

Comment: @RRUZ, I'd say it's better to try [Preview Handlers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/cc144143) instead.

Answer (score 4):

`...that the windows explorer does not use a preview handler to preview the images.` When I said that i mean for the standard image formats like gif, jpeg, bmp, png and so on. For another custom formats you must implement a Preview handler, additionally  you can register a thumbnail using a [Thumbnail Handlers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144118%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and the [IThumbnailProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774614%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) interface.

Comment: In case you don't fully grasp this, what you must do is implement a preview handler and register it with the shell. You implement this **outside** your delphi app. That's because it is the shell that displays previews in a file dialog, even if the dialog is hosted in your app.

Comment: Thanks David.  It is much more complicated than I would have thought,  but thanks for your help.